# how to access chield model from parent model (using Multi-table inheritance)

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

### how to accsees  **serves_pizza**  from parent moddel (Place)

my use case , i need to access **serves_pizza**  from parent serilizer (PlaceSerializer)

```
class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    serves_pizza = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = '__all__'
def get_serves_pizza (self, obj):
    serves_pizza = Restaurant.objects.get(**???**)
   
    return serves_pizza
```

Answer (score 0):

If `obj` is the Place inside that `get_serves_pizza` function, then something like this would work.  I only tested it inside the shell, not a with Serializer

```py
serves_pizza = Restaurant.objects.get(name=obj.name).serves_pizza
```

---

but I'd advice against uses `.get()` and instead use `.filter().first()` so if the Place isn't a Restaurant the program doesn't crash.

```py
# restaurantObj will either be the object or None
restaurantObj = Restaurant.objects.filter(name=obj.name).first()

serves_pizza = restaurantObj.serves_pizza if restaurantObj else False
# do other attributes
serves_hot_dogs = restaurantObj.serves_hot_dogs if restaurantObj else False
# ..etc
```